# Failed to symbolic-link /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic to initrd.img: File exists

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get

Since running an upgrade today I am no longer able to use apt-get.

Case in point:

```
sudo apt-get install curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
curl is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Setting up linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic (3.2.0-24.38) ...
Running depmod.
Failed to symbolic-link /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic to initrd.img: File exists
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 17
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

As far as I can work out, this is what it's failing on:

```
sudo dpkg --configure linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic
Setting up linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic (3.2.0-24.38) ...
Running depmod.
Failed to symbolic-link /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic to initrd.img: File exists
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 17
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic
```

However, when I run this everything seems to be working...

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic.postinst
echo $?
0
```

What on earth is going on? I'm a little scared of messing around since I assume this is critical stuff...

Comment: I fixed it by uninstalling and installing again. Nothing else worked...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I removed the `initrd` symlink from my root directory by running

```
sudo rm /initrd.img
```

but if you want to have a failsafe against that you can of course backup the existing `initrd.img` before deleting it.

Then run

```
sudo apt-get -f install [package]
```

and it should be able to run through successfully.

Comment: The problem occurred again and this time I've taken your solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo apt-get -f install [package]
```

This will force the upgrade. It's worth a try at least. Doing an

```
sudo apt-get update
```

can't hurt either.